# How do I extract an ISO on Linux without root access

Tags: linux, extract, iso-image

I have a large ISO file on a server, and I need to access the file in it, without having root access. Thus, I can't simply mount it. What should I do to be able to extract an ISO on LInux without root access?

Answer (score 30):

If 7zip is installed this one is really easy:

```
7z x Your.iso -oWhere/You/Want/It/Extracted/To
```

to extract the whole iso.

Comment: Since the OP's question has a "linux" tag it's important to state this won't work with `7za` (CentOS); `7za` does not support ISO archives. You can check supported formats with `7za i`.

Comment: FYI `7z` seems smart enough to extract directly off media: `7z x /dev/cdrom`. I have very stupid issue, that my files show up 0 bytes when mounted. So extracting was a workaround.

Comment: Just to enforce, **-o** should be without space

Answer (score 21):

Many of the GUI tools like file roller will use [isoinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/1/isoinfo) in the background.

You can extract a single file from an ISO like so:

```
isoinfo -i image.iso -x /isolinux/initrd.img > initrd.img
```

The redirection is required as `-x` extracts to stdout.

If you'd like to list contents of a folder in the ISO:

```
isoinfo -i image.iso -l
```

example output:

```
Directory listing of /
d---------   0    0    0            2048      0 1900 [     26 02]  .
d---------   0    0    0            2048      0 1900 [     26 02]  ..
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Feb  6 2010 [     27 02]  i386
...
```

Comment: To use isoread to extract all the files, try this script: https://github.com/goblinhack/isoread

Comment: @NeilMcGill Doesn't work here. Lots of errors.

Comment: ISO with Rock Ridge extensions will require uppercase filenames with ";1" appended at the end. Use -Rl to list the files in this form.

Answer (score 10):

I found a new best way: using `xorriso`!

No need to have root access. I've tried `7z` and `file-roller`, both of them don't work here.

`xorriso` is an open-source program, so you can download the source codes if you don't have it installed by default.

If you haven't installed it, please download the source codes here: https://www.gnu.org/software/xorriso/

The steps are:

```
tar zxvf xorriso-1.4.6.tar.gz
cd xorriso-1.4.6
./configure
make
cd xorriso
pwd
```

Add the output directory into environment variable `PATH`.

---

Then, you can use it to extract an iso file:

```
xorriso -osirrox on -indev image.iso -extract / extracted_path
```

You just need to modify `image.iso` and `extracted_path` to make it work on your system.

---

Referred: https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2014/08/26/how-to-extract-an-iso-image/

Answer (score 5):

If you have GUI access, right click the iso, and choose "Open with Archive Manager..." or simply run:

```
file-roller -e /path/to/extract/to /path/to/iso
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of the above solutions make you extract the iso content, but if the content is large it will take lot of space.

A better solution would be to do the actual mounting of the iso image, and thanks to [FuseISO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fuseiso/) that is possible without root access (but you would still need to ask the admin to install FuseISO if it is not already installed, in ubuntu `sudo apt-get install fuseiso`)

Once you have FuseISO installed in the machine you can:

```
# For user to mount an iso file:
mkdir ~/iso
fuseiso ~/my_iso.iso ~/iso
# For user to unmount an iso file:
fusermount -u ~/iso
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `7-zip` or `unrar` installed you can use to either extract iso's.

Comment: What's the syntax for `unrar`? I think that's for Winrar only

Answer (score 1):

If you can mount FUSE filesystems, [FuseISO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuseiso/) is an option for mounting the image.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mount it.  ISO is just like any other storage file, like a .zip.  There are a lot of iso specific tools to do the trick which you should be able to compile as a user, but the easiest way should be to do:

```
file-roller -h filename.iso
```